# Space-filling polyhedra (or honeycomb) survey?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, polyhedra

Is there a survey anywhere of space-filling polyhedra?  MathWorld's article, [space-filling polyhedron](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Space-FillingPolyhedron.html), mentions about 400 being seen in pre-1981 books and papers. Wikipedia mentions [28 convex uniform honeycombs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_uniform_honeycomb), and the article [honeycomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeycomb_%28geometry%29).

Is there a modern count anywhere for how many space-filling hexahedra or icosahedra exist?  Can the 3D coordinates be downloaded?

Comment: From your MathWorld link: "In the period 1974-1980, Michael Goldberg attempted to exhaustively catalog space-filling polyhedra. According to Goldberg, there are 27 distinct space-filling hexahedra..."  Are you looking for any possible updates?

Comment: Yep.  Is that number 27 still reliable?  From the later papers, it seems Goldberg missed a lot.  Is there data solid enough to support an integer sequence for OEIS?

Comment: What sort of integer sequence did you have in mind?  Tesselations by dimension, or some restricted-to-3D concept?

Comment: In 2D, for n-gons 3-6, there are 1,1,14,3 families of tiling polygons, according to Grunbaum. In 3D, 3-12, there are 5,?,27,56,49,?,?,40,16 types of space-filling polyhedra, according to MathWorld. For example, there are 5 spacefilling tetrahedra.

Comment: There are infinitely many spacefilling polyhedra. Many are trivial, for example a cube with three mutually adjacent dimpled faces and three mutually adjacent augmented faces will fill space in just the same arrangement as the cube, though with lower symmetry. Of more interest is the number of possible arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

No. A full count only applies to simple cases with given constraints.

Regarding the space-filling tetrahedra please note that there is an infinite number of those. Among those who fill space by isometries, it is known that there are 9 topological families.

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FPL00009423#page-1

Comment: For tetrahedra, have you seen: Senechal, Marjorie. "Which tetrahedra fill space?." Mathematics Magazine (1981): 227-243.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many polyhedra which can fill space, among which can be found a very large number of distinct topologies. Beyond specific topics such as high symmetries, quasiregularity and so on there are no systematising principles and it is impossible to keep track. The fact that the concept of a spacefilling polyhedron is often stretched to include solids which self-intersect or have curved faces (such as bubbles in a  foam) just makes it even harder.

If you do find a survey, it will not be worth very much.